# Swashbuckle(swagger) exposes other namespaces in JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, swashbuckle

We have a public api, this is isolated in its own project(xxx.ClientApi) running asp.net (MVC). 
Here we have Swashbuckle.Core version 5.6.0.

So all is good, our swagger is generated and it looks amazing, so all is good. But as soon as we jump to our Json swagger file:
/swagger/docs/v1.0

We will see alot of namespaces being exposed, and even namespaces that is not directly in the isolated project. There is nothing about these in the project and neither in the generated XML file we are basing the swagger around.

How can I control this? I cannot seem to figure this out, cannot find any posts on it, so now i will ask instead :)

This is our Config:

```
 GlobalConfiguration
                .Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.RootUrl(ResolveBasePath);
                    c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
                    c.ResolveConflictingActions(a => a.First());
                    c.DescribeAllEnumsAsStrings();

                    //SWASHBUCKLE.EXAMPLES
                    c.OperationFilter<ExamplesOperationFilter>();
                    c.OperationFilter<DescriptionOperationFilter>();

                    //CUSTOM
                    c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerDocumentFilter>();
                    c.OperationFilter<Consumes>();

                    //COMMENTS 
                    var xmlFile = "XML documentation\\" + $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
                    var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath);

                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1.0", "Api api")
                    .Contact(cc => cc
                            .Name("Names")
                            .Url("https://www.example.com")
                            .Email("mymail@mails.com"));


                })
                .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
                {
                    c.DisableValidator();
                    c.DocExpansion(DocExpansion.List);
                });
```

**EDIT #1**:
@Helder Sepulveda, it could be like this:
An example could be this:
[image]

And it is probobly me who is missing something.

**EDIT #2**:
So i tried that, but it only removes the deeplinking of namespaces.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your `/swagger/docs/v1.0` not sure what those namespaces being exposed could be... Do you see namespaces here: http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/V1

Comment: Added a screenshot to my main post, hope that gives some insight to it :) @HelderSepulveda

Comment: I think the option called `UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds`  might be doing that

Comment: Added a new screenshot, sadly didnt do much :(

Comment: Not sure what's the problem with the second screenshot, those look OK

Comment: Sorry, the issue is that definitions like "treenode" is not part of my project. Its part of a  package that is in my project, but not in anyway referenced throughout my project. So the issue is, that "definitions" in my swagger is getting floated by items from other references in my project, but not used in my project. So what i wanted is to only have definitions that is actually used by the endpoints im publishing.

Comment: that "treenode" must be used somewhere, definitions are not added just for fun... search on the JSON that must be used in action as an input parameter or response output. Without actual code reproducing your issue is very difficult to answer your questions, can you create a minimal project reproducing this?

Comment: Ill dive into it and create a small dummy project, thank you so far!